# Expectation of balls chosen

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose the next game with $n$ balls and $n$ boxes:

1. The balls are distributed in the boxes radomly
2. $n$ boxes are chosen randomly (the choice can be repeated)
3. Let $X_i$ be the number of balls in the $i$'th chosen box and let $X=\sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}$

I want to calculate $EX$ but not sure about my calculation. I know that the expected size of each box is $1$ since it's distributed by $Binom(n,1/n)$, but does that mean that $EX_i=1$? Or maybe $EX_i=n$ since there are $n$ options to choose from?

By empirically testing (with a computer program) $X$ was close to $n$ so $EX_i=1$ makes a lot of sense, but not sure if it's correct.

Comment: You said you know the expected size of each box is $1$; since $X_i$ chooses a random box that means its expected value is also $1$ (in general it would be the average of the expected sizes of each box, if those numbers happened to be different).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan so the math is correct? It seems weird this is the expected value since some boxes might have a lot more than 1

Comment: Some boxes will, but not very many. We can say it more precisely as follows: let $Y_i$ be the number of balls in the $i^{th}$ original box (in step 1, before the random selection of boxes). We agree that $\mathbb{E}(Y_i) = 1$, yes? Then each $X_i$, by definition, takes on each of the values $Y_1, \dots Y_n$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$ each, so $\mathbb{E}(X_i) = \frac{\sum \mathbb{E}(Y_i)}{n} = 1$. Is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks! I haven't thought about it in that way. It's much clearer now:)

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about something. Where did the $\mathbb{E}(Y_i)$ come from?

Comment: Formally, this is an application of the law of total expectation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation